# I can't display any result in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

i'm developing a web app and I can't display any result to my crystal report. i don't know what is wrong in my code. please help.

```
    Dim cnn As SqlConnection
    Dim connectionString As String
    Dim sql As String
    connectionString = "data source=SERVERNAME; _
    initial catalog=crystaldb;user id=sa;password=PASSWORD;"
    cnn = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    cnn.Open()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM Grades
    Dim dscmd As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet1
    dscmd.Fill(ds, "Grades")
    objRpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(1))
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt
    CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Comment: I was also facing many problems at load time try these links.
[Try this](http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-stepbystep.htm) [Or try this ](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166291/Generate-a-report-using-Crystal-Reports-in-Visual)